# Method to take `T extends Iterable` and return T<E>?

Tags: java, generics

How do I write a method that takes a parameter of some type `T` which is an instance of `Iterable`, as well as a parameter of `Class<E>`, and return `T<E>`?

```
public static <...> ... checkedCast(T iterable, Class<E> clazz) {
    // Check elements and throw ClassCastException if invalid

    @SupressWarning("checked")
    ... cast = (...)iterable;
    return cast;
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
// This should compile
ArrayList<?> a = ...;
ArrayList<String> b = checkedCast(a, String.class);

// So should this
HashSet<Number> c = ...;
Set<Integer> d = checkedCast(c, Integer.class);

// This shouldn't compile
b = checkedCast(a, Integer.class);

// This shouldn't compile
b = checkedCast(c, Integer.class);

// This should throw ClassCastException
checkedCast(a, Integer.class);
```

I know I can do this using overrides, but this requires me to write an override for every type:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> checkedCast(Iterable<?> iterable, Class<T> clazz) {...}
public static <T> List<T> checkedCast(List<?> list, Class<T> clazz) {...}
public static <T> ArrayList<T> checkedCast(ArrayList<?> list, Class<T> clazz) {...}
public static <T> Set<T> checkedCast(Set<?> set, Class<T> clazz) {...}
```

Comment: Why do you want a method like this at all? It sounds like you're doing something else funky.

Comment: It's some sort of nonsense, if you think that an interface is already an abstraction.

Comment: Some library methods return `List<?>` or `List`, even though I know they're actually `List<X>` because of context.  However, an unlikely and unexpected input could lead them to return `List<Y>` in which case I'd want it to fail-fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the weaknesses of the Java type system's Generics extension is that how we think about types in the singular doesn't scale to how we think of types in the plural.

In short, Collections of a generic type cannot be safely cast, ever.  Build a new list, pull out each type and check it individually, and the return the new list.  If you disregard this warning, I'll direct someone to do something like

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
customers.add(new Customer(...));
List<Object> customerObjects = checkCast(customers, Object.class);
customerObjects.add(new Order(...));
```

You have been warned.

Comment: Oh, right..  I hadn't considered this!  It'll be safe if I changed to the return an immutable `List` wouldn't it?  (In which case generic `extends Iterable` go out of the question I suppose.)

Comment: Oh, even immutable lists it wouldn't be safe because unchecked elements of different types could be added to the original iterable afterwards..

Comment: +1 This doesn't directly answer the question, but it makes the question a non-question.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. But, people can help you better if you can describe in more detail why you need such a method.

```
public static
<InputElement, OutputElement extends InputElement,
 InputContainer extends Iterable<InputElement>,
 OutputContainer extends Iterable<OutputElement>>
OutputContainer checkedCast(InputContainer iterable,
                            Class<OutputElement> clazz) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  OutputContainer output = (OutputContainer) iterable;
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works/matches your requirements - except for throwing a ClassCastException (if you really want that behaviour, you can include it in the checkedCast method yourself):

```
import java.util.*;

public class CheckedCast {

    public static <GenB, GenA extends GenB, CollA extends List<GenA>> List<GenB> checkedCast(CollA iterable, Class<GenB> clazz){
        return (List<GenB>)iterable;
    }
    public static <GenB, GenA extends GenB, CollA extends Set<GenA>> Set<GenB> checkedCast(CollA iterable, Class<GenB> clazz){
        return (Set<GenB>)iterable;
    }

    static class One {}
    static class Two extends One {}
    static class Three {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Two> test1 = new ArrayList<Two>();
        List<One> test2 = checkedCast(test1, One.class);

        // Shouldn't compile...
        ArrayList<One> aa = checkedCast(test2, One.class);  // output is ArrayList
        List<Two> bb = checkedCast(test2, Three.class);     // Three is not superClass of Two
        ArrayList cc = checkedCast(new HashSet(), Integer.class);           // Set cannot become List
        ArrayList<One> dd = checkedCast(new LinkedList<One>(), One.class);  // ArrayList is not superClass of List
    }

}
```

**Updated to match new requirement:** ArrayList xs = checkedCast(new HashSet(), Integer.class) - shouldn't compile

**Update:** updated to assert returned Collection generic type extends input Collection's generic type.

Comment: The problem with this is that there's an unchecked cast from `T` to `B`.  (Not the element's type, but the iterable's type.)  So `ArrayList<Integer> xs = checkedCast(new HashSet<Integer>(), Integer.class)` wouldn't emit a compilation error.

Comment: Hi @antak, I've updated the answer to handle your new requirement. The methods are now dependent on the `java.lang.Iterable` implementation. I haven't worked out a generic way to do all implementations of Iterable in one single method (yet). I believe this matches all your requirements?

Comment: I tried it this way and I couldn't get it to work.  (That's actually why I decided to ask here on SO.)  The problem with this way is that `collB instanceof CollA` still isn't enforced at compile time.  For example, in your new code, I can still write `ArrayList<One> xs = checkedCast(new LinkedList<One>(), One.class)` and get it to compile.

Comment: @antak, I've made one last change, so that the methods only return the Set or List super class type (this should address your last comment). If you want it to return ArrayList (or a superClass of ArrayList), I'm not sure how to do it at this point.